# Class 'Datatables' not found Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, datatables, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and php version is 5.6.

I am getting error "Class 'Datatables' not found". I am following standard procedure. I have installed datatable using composer by following command:

```
composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"~7.0"
```

I added these two lines in config->app file in service provider and aliases:

```
Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
'DataTables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
```

then publish package :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider
```

I am using raw query here is my controller code :

```
function allvendor(){
    $sql="my query";
    $results=DB::table(DB::raw("($sql)"));
    return Datatables::of($results)->make(true);
}
```

Comment: The error itself is because the AJAX response that DataTables is receiving is not in the expected format. Does the response from the endpoint you've set up look valid? Have you customised the DataTables ajax options on the client side?

Answer (score 8):

It's a typo. You set alias as `DataTables` but returned is `Datatables`.